# Button Handlers in Android App

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add multiple button handlers for my app. I have successfully created one button that links to a web page. I am running into trouble with my next button, however. I want to go to a new screen on click. I have create the new screen xml file and the corresponding java file. I have also added the activity to the manifest. I'm just not sure how to add multiple button handlers to the main java page. I have attached how I did my first button. Any advice on how to add a second handler to this page for a button that will change view?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          Intent browserIntent = 
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://m.noblenet.org/eg/opac/home?locg=1"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, please give more and clear information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly then buttons appear through onCreateOptionsMenu logic.
Best way to handle the click events in this case would be to override onOptionsItemSelected API. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) for more details

Comment: Thank you, I will check out that link now.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways of handling button click is to use android:onClick attribute in xml file for a button view. For example in Button View of your xml add android:onClick="clickMe"
and in your java code write Public void clickMe(View view) { //do something on button click }